# Why host_row_pitch should not be less than region[0] in clEnqueueWriteBufferRect

Tags: c++, copy, buffer, opencl, gpu

I want to write data from host to device in openCL by using `clEnqueueWriteBufferRect`. I used the code below

```
int deviceWidth = roundUp(width_x, WGX); \\rounup width_x to the first multiply of WGX
int deviceHeight = height_x;
int deviceDataSize = deviceWidth * deviceHeight * sizeof(float);
buffer_x = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  deviceDataSize);

cl::size_t<3> buffer_origin;
  buffer_origin[0] = 0;
  buffer_origin[1] = 0;
  buffer_origin[2] = 0;

  cl::size_t<3> host_origin;
  host_origin[0] = 0;
  host_origin[1] = 0;
  host_origin[2] = 0;

  cl::size_t<3> region;
  region[0] = (size_t)(deviceWidth * sizeof(float));
  region[1] = (size_t)height_x;
  region[2] = 1;

  std::cout << "===> Start writing data to device" << std::endl;
    queue.enqueueWriteBufferRect(buffer_x, CL_TRUE, buffer_origin, host_origin, region ,deviceWidth_x * sizeof(float), 0, width_x * sizeof(float), 0, x);
```

`x` has a dimension of `width_x * height_x`. and when I run the code I got the error `CL_INVALID_VALUE`. The reason of the problem in `region[0] > host_row_pitch`. But I can not understand the reason of the limit, since usually region in host is smaller that region in device, i.e. you want to copy data from host to in a middle of device with padding. Therefor the area in host memory may be smaller that area in device. Am I wrong?

Comment: `region` specifies the size of the area *that you are actually copying*. You can't copy more data than is available. What are you trying to accomplish with this, exactly? What data are you expecting the rest of the region to be filled with? Note that the destination image will already have a specific dimension that you specified when creating it, so `region` is definitely *not* the size of the destination image, but the the area within it you are trying to update.

Comment: Thanks @pmdj for the comment. Now it makes sense, since I thought `region` is the area used to copy data on. But What would happen if `host_row_pitch` is larger than actual data size? for example if `x` is an array of `(10,10)` and we choose `host_row_pitch = 12`.